# Need a way to add function to an ever-changing html (ul) list

Tags: jquery, html

I've been thinking a bit about how to add a function to '.click()' event on a `<ul>`'s very own `<li>`s. First thing would be simple with (it's approximative, I'm not a jquery pro obviously).

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('.prodli').each().click( //prodli is my class I set on every <li>
            function () {
                //blabla
            }
        );
    }
);
```

BUT! Because there's always a but somewhere... Thing is these `<li>` can be removed added through another jquery script.

So if I apply previous script I wrote above on this list:

```
<ul>
    <li productId="1" class="prodli">Product 1</li>
    <li productId="2" class="prodli">Product 2</li>
    <li productId="3" class="prodli">Product 3</li>
    <li productId="4" class="prodli">Product 4</li>
    <li productId="5" class="prodli">Product 5</li>
    <li productId="6" class="prodli">Product 6</li>
</ul>
```

I suppose that if with some other scripts I update the list to be something like

```
<ul>
    <li productId="455" class="prodli">Product 455</li>
    <li productId="48" class="prodli">Product 48</li>
    <li productId="7" class="prodli">Product 7</li>
</ul>
```

I should re-call my first script to apply the `click()` function to these new `<li>`, right?

Is there a way to do it in a more global way? I mean something like "every time an element with class "prodli" is clicked, apply this function" ? Or something like every `<li>` from this specific `<ul>` list ?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delegate the click event to the parent `ul` element (or any other ancestor really). Since DOM events tend to bubble up the tree, any click on a descendant element will reach the `ul` and can be handled there.

jQuery provides the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to do so (if you're using an older version of jQuery you will need [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of `on`):

```
$("ul").on("click", ".prodli", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

This means the children of the `ul` can change as much as you like. It won't make a difference. Any click on any descendant of the `ul` will bubble up to the `ul`. jQuery checks to see if the click originated on an element matching the selector (in this case, any `.prodli` element), and if so it executes the event handler.

Comment: And, using this way if I use $(this) will it be <li> element or <ul> ? My guess is <li> but I'm not sure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser - No problem. Yes, `this` it will refer to the clicked `li` element.